# Cisco port security static vs sticky+static

Tags: cisco, switch, network-access, port-security

I don't see a different between the two. Both make it to the running config.

1) sticky + static

```
Switch1(config-if)#switchport port-security mac-address sticky ?
  H.H.H  48 bit mac address

Switch1(config-if)#switchport port-security mac-address sticky ae11.be22.ce33
```

2) static only

```
Switch1(config-if)#switchport port-security mac-address ?
  H.H.H   48 bit mac address

Switch1(config-if)#switchport port-security mac-address ae12.be22.ce33
```

In Running Config

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
 switchport access vlan 4
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 5
 switchport priority extend trust
 switchport port-security maximum 5
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky
 **switchport port-security mac-address sticky ae11.be22.ce33
 switchport port-security mac-address ae12.be22.ce33**
 duplex full
 mls qos trust cos
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
```

!

Confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is pretty straightforward.

```
switchport port-security mac-address sticky
```

Will convert all dynamically learned MAC addresses to sticky MAC addresses so that you don't have to statically define them (like if you had a couple hundred hosts).

```
switchport port-security mac-address sticky ae11.be22.ce33
```

Simply allows you to ensure that one is added statically (as you already know).  Statically defined MACs are also preserved in the configuration, so after a reboot they would not need to be relearned.

From [Configuring Port Security](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/20ewa/configuration/guide/conf/port_sec.html)

> You can configure an interface to convert the dynamic MAC addresses to
>   sticky secure MAC addresses and to add them to the running
>   configuration by enabling sticky learning. To enable sticky learning,
>   enter the `switchport port-security mac-address sticky` command. When
>   you enter this command, the interface converts all the dynamic secure
>   MAC addresses, including those that were dynamically learned before
>   sticky learning was enabled, to sticky secure MAC addresses.
>
> The sticky secure MAC addresses do not automatically become part of
>   the configuration file, which is the startup configuration used each
>   time the switch restarts. If you save the sticky secure MAC addresses
>   in the configuration file, when the switch restarts, the interface
>   does not need to relearn these addresses. If you do not save the
>   configuration, they are lost.

So in your configurations case, you statically defining those MAC addresses is just redundant, anything learned on that port will be converted to a sticky MAC anyway.

Comment: ahh... tts the difference..